# feature extraction for adding new dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, feature-extraction

Is there any algorithms for in the scope of feature extraction for adding new dimensions ?
probably this is a general question and there is not particular technical situation for me, indeed  I need a general answer and maybe someone could introduce some known algorithms in feature extraction which basically used for adding new feature based on existing ones .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Of course there is. A simple one is to add squares of features, triples etc: for  features `x1, x2, x3`, add `x1^2, x2^2, x3^2, x1x2, x1x3, x2x3` for example. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @IVlad , Yes it is , but i wondering is there any algorithm for doing this automatically based on entropy or something like that or approaches like PCA which applied for dimensionality reduction . by the way what you mentioned was helpful.thanks

Comment: Maybe there is something, but I doubt it. Usually you want to reduce the number of features to help your algorithms: PCA and others are for dimensionality reduction when you just need fewer features but you don't have a way of really knowing which are more important, feature selection (with Chi Square and others) for things like bag of words models, neural networks extract higher level features in their early layers and feed them to the next layers etc. Every (non-toy) approach I know of leads to fewer features, not more.

Comment: In addition to @IVlad's comments, I would say that in general any combination of models can be regarded as a way to "extend the dimension". For example, you could start with a linear regression, then apply another linear regression (or any other model) to the residual, and so on.